# setscal in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this programme:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.21556788990002");
        System.out.println(a.setScale(2));
```

I have result `0.21` but when i want to extract just `0.2` i try

> for(int i=1; i<10; i++) System.out.println(a.setScale(i));

I have this error when i= 1:

> at java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:1439)  at
>   java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2390)   at
>   java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2437)   at
>   NewClass.main(NewClass.java:30)

What i can do to extract with i = 1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use rounding mode for scale, for Your case it will the following:

```
System.out.println(a.setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW This is similar to

```
double a = 0.21556788990002;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.printf("%." + i + "f%n", a);
```

prints

```
0.2
0.22
0.216
0.2156
0.21557
0.215568
0.2155679
0.21556789
0.215567890
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `overloaded` **setScale method** which takes rounding as an second argument.
refer to it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,int%29)

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.21556788990002");
    System.out.println(a.setScale(1,1)); //result 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use decimal format as well:

```
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.21556788990002");

        //change any desired format using 0 or #
        DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        System.out.println(dFormat.format(a)); //< - print 0.2

        DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
        System.out.println(dFormat.format(a)); //< - print .2

        DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println(dFormat.format(a)); //< - print 0.21
```